# It is so lovely a day

Tags: phrases, american-english, british-english

I know "such a lovely day" is definitely correct, but what do you think of "it's so lovely a day"? Is it okay as well?

[image]

This part of an exercise I did in FCE use of English, 'it's so lovely day' is used within the whole sentence so perhaps in that context it makes some sense? I believe I was perplexed when I saw it for the first time, but sadly, I'm still jumbled.

Answer (score 4):

> "it's so lovely a day"?

I am going to 100% disagree with Bella swan, and say it is perfectly lovely, it is a bit quaint I wouldn't use it everyday but I can quite imagine myself saying

> it's so lovely a day, lets go for a picnic

I would be being intentionally twee, I would be imagining wicker picnic baskets, boys playing cricket, bees buzzing and a stream burbling*.

[image: the picnic in my minde]

---

- [burbling stream youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GrnH2oei0A)